# Update dataset from sql C#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have a kiosk that is used for visitor sign in, when they sign in it sends the data to a SQL db. I then pull this data into a dataset then into a datagridview on the monitoring application. This data is refreshed every 15 seconds.

How can I update this dataset/datagridview without grabbing all the data every time? The initial pull is about 500 lines, I don't want to pull all those same 500 everytime. I want to check to see if there are any new records and add them to the dataset.

Here is the code where I get the data

```
private void UpdateUsers()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ConnectSQL("10.100.25.250", "bhi_kiosk");
        var query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uStatus=1", conn);
        SqlDataReader read = null;
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        conn.Open();
        read = query.ExecuteReader();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(read);
        query.Connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: So you want to get the updated data from the server (so you can display it in the datagridview) without having to run a query on the server?  Is that right?  Just making sure I didn't mis-read the question.

Comment: Keep a track of the last query time, then change your query to `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uStatus=1 AND signInTime > @lastRunTime`

Comment: Are you saying when they sign in, you pull all of the data, then from that point forward, you want to keep what hasn't been updated and only get the new stuff? Will the stuff you want to pull in be updated records AND new records or just new records?

Comment: Paddy is looking like he is on the right track. I need to compare the stored data with the remote data and merge the differences. The local data is static while the remote data changes as people sign in.

Comment: Okay. If you want to answer someone directly in comments, use "@Yatrix" or "@Paddy" and it'll notify them so they can respond back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the data at the start:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DateTime lastChange = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1);
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    UpdateUsers();
}
```

And then [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) new DataTable into old one:

```
private void UpdateUsers()
{
    SqlConnection conn = ConnectSQL("10.100.25.250", "bhi_kiosk");
    var query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uStatus=1 AND LastChange > @LastChange ORDER BY LastChange", conn);
    var lastChangeparameter = query.Parameters.Add("@LastChange", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    lastChangeparameter.Value = lastChange;
    //listView1.Items.Clear();
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader read = query.ExecuteReader())
    {
        using (var dt_merge = new DataTable())
        {
            dt_merge.Load(read);
            dt.Merge(dt_merge);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lastChange = (DateTime)dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["LastChange"];
            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

You will get what you want. Couple of pointers: there really should be a try ... catch block to ensure conn is disposed in case of error. Query depends on order by LastChange because next reading time is taken from maximum (LastChange). You use datetime from server to avoid possibility of loosing a record if client time is not perfectly aligned with server time.

Comment: I can't vouch for the code being exact, but his idea is spot on.