# how to use update method in DataAdapter in C#

Tags: c#

I just simply want to update the edited result in to the database, that is edited in the datagridView, so the user don't have to see any popup or any thing else to Edit the value,

I have this code but its not working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.Skins;
using DevExpress.LookAndFeel;
using DevExpress.UserSkins;
using DevExpress.XtraBars;
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon;
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Helpers;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace e_Examiner {
    public partial class Form1 : RibbonForm {
        Library lib = new Library();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet table;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitSkinGallery();
            InitGrid();
        }

        void InitSkinGallery() {
            SkinHelper.InitSkinGallery(rgbiSkins, true);
        }

        void InitGrid() {
            lib.connectionOpen();
            OleDbCommand commnad = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM teachers",         
               lib.dbConnection);
            table = new DataSet();
            adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(commnad);
            OleDbCommandBuilder bulder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(table, "teachers");
            gridControl.DataSource = table.Tables["teachers"];
            lib.connectionClose();
        }

        private void layoutView1_CellValueChanged_1(object sender,          
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.
            CellValueChangedEventArgs e) {

            lib.connectionOpen();
            OleDbCommandBuilder bulder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
            DataTable dt = table.Tables["teachers"];
            adapter.Update(dt);
            lib.connectionClose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686205/update-dataset-from-sql-c-sharp/10687376#10687376